# How to draw a figure by seaborn pairplot in several rows?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a dataset with 76 features and 1 dependent variable (y). I use seaborn to draw pairplot between features and y in Jupyter notebook. Since the No. of features is high, size of plot for every feature is very small, as can be seen below:

[image]

I am looking for a way to draw pairplot in several rows. Also, I don't want to copy and paste pairplot code in several cells in notebook. I am looking for a way to make this figure automatically.

The code I am using (I cannot share dataset, so I use a sample dataset):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
data = pd.concat([X, y], axis=1)

y_name = 'y'
features_names = [f'feature_{i}' for i in range(1, X.shape[1]+1)]  
column_names = features_names + [y_name]
data.columns = column_names

plot_size=7
num_plots_x=5   # No. of plots in every row
num_plots_y = math.ceil(len(features_names)/num_plots_x)   # No. of plots in y direction

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(plot_size*num_plots_y, plot_size*num_plots_x), facecolor='white')
axes = [fig.add_subplot(num_plots_y,1,i+1) for i in range(num_plots_y)]   

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):   
    start_index = i * num_plots_x
    end_index = (i+1) * num_plots_x
    if end_index > len(features_names): end_index = len(features_names)
    sns.pairplot(x_vars=features_names[start_index:end_index], y_vars=y_name, data = data)

plt.savefig('figure.png')
```

The above code has two problems. It shows empty box at the top of the figure and then it shows the pairplots. Following is part of the figure that I get.

[image]

Second problem is that it only saves the last row as png file, not the whole figure.

If you have any idea to solve this, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: when I run it directly (`python script.py`) then it opens every row in separated window and so it treats it as separated objects and it saves in file only last object. Other problem is that `sns` doesn't need `fig` and `axes` - it can't use `subplots` to put all in one image - and when I remove `fig` `axes` then it stops showing first window with empty box.

Comment: I found that `FacetGrid` has `col_wrap` to put in many rows. And I found that someone suggested to add this `col_wrap` in `pairplot` - [Add parameter col_wrap to pairplot #2121](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2121) and they show how to do it  with `FacetGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run it directly (`python script.py`) then it opens every row in separated window - so it treats it as separated objects and it saves in file only last object.

Other problem is that `sns` doesn't need `fig` and `axes` - it can't use `subplots` to put all on one image - and when I remove `fig` `axes` then it stops showing first window with empty box.

---

I found that `FacetGrid` has `col_wrap` to put in many rows. And I found that someone suggested to add this `col_wrap` in `pairplot` - [Add parameter col_wrap to pairplot #2121](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2121) and there is also example how to `FacetGrid` with `scatterplot` instead of `pairplot` and then it can use `col_wrap`.

---

Here is code which use `FacetGrid` with `col_wrap`

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
data = pd.concat([X, y], axis=1)

y_name = 'y'
features_names = [f'feature_{i}' for i in range(1, X.shape[1]+1)]  
column_names = features_names + [y_name]
data.columns = column_names

plot_size=7
num_plots_x=5   # No. of plots in every row
num_plots_y = math.ceil(len(features_names)/num_plots_x)   # No. of plots in y direction

'''
for i in range(num_plots_y):
    start = i * num_plots_x
    end = start + num_plots_x
    sns.pairplot(x_vars=features_names[start:end], y_vars=y_name, data=data)
'''

g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.DataFrame(features_names), col=0, col_wrap=4, sharex=False)
for ax, x_var in zip(g.axes, features_names):
    sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=x_var, y=y_name, ax=ax)
g.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('figure.png')
plt.show()
```

Result (`'figure.png'`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
data = pd.concat([X, y], axis=1)

y_name = 'y'
features_names = [f'feature_{i}' for i in range(1, X.shape[1]+1)]  
column_names = features_names + [y_name]
data.columns = column_names


fig, axes = plt.subplots(int(np.ceil(len(column_names)/3)), 3, figsize = (20,20))
for i, att in zip(range(len(column_names)), column_names):
    sns.scatterplot(ax = axes[int(np.floor(i/3))][i%3], 
                    x = att, y = 'y', data = data,
                    alpha = 0.8)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0JEk.png)

Comment: subplot , np.ceil , sns.scatterplot , seaborn pairplot in several rows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).